# Webform upload files issue

Tags: webforms, files

I have setup our site to allow files to be uploaded and attached to the submission of the webform. I have the private directory setup with the .htaccess file. That part seems to be ok because when I add the upload element to the webform it creates a folder in the private directory and adds a sample file to it. When I try to use the form and add files to be uploaded and then submit the data it give me this error "File upload in progress. Uploaded file may be lost. Do you want to continue?" The webform is sent with the pdf of the data to the recipient without the files attached. How do I troubleshoot this issue?
Running Drupal Core 9.3.12 Webforms 6.1.3 Entity Print 8.x-2.5
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post here the YAML of a minimal form that exhibits the bug?

Comment: So I figured out it the problem is there are two many elements on the form. If I remove elements the attachment of files element works correctly. I have a custom theme that I did not create. Could the theme be limiting the length of the form or is there a setting I am missing somewhere?

Comment: Can you post here the YAML of a minimal form that exhibits the bug?